# Value Independent Knapsack Problems using Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have searched all the sites. But knapsack problem is always with weights and values.

I have to write algorithm and C++ implementation for the following problem..

Problem:

The knapsack problem is that given a set of positive integers (a1,.....,an) and a knapsack of size s, find a subset A of (a1,.....,an) such that sum of elements in A is largest but at most s.

Have to use dynamic programming to design algorithm for this. Also have to prove correctness and have to calculate the computational time for this.

Can you provide any useful resource for this. Can anyone explain how to do this? Because throughout the web i can find only the knapsack problems with weights and values.

This problem is somewhat special case..

Please post soon....

Answer (score 0):

This is the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is a private instance of knapsack where `cost[i] = weight[i]` for each item `i`.

The DP solution follows the following recursive formula:

```
D(0,i) = true
D(x,i) = false        x < 0
D(x,0) = false        x > 0
D(x,i) = D(x-arr[i],i-1) OR D(x,i-1)
```

At the end, the highest value of `x<=S` such that `D(x,n) = true`, is the highest possible value that is at most S.